# Count per month if unique

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get a SQL query to count `personid` unique for the month, is a 'Returning' visitor unless they have a record of  'New' for the month as well.

```
month |    personid   | visitstat
---------------------------------
January     john          new
January     john          returning
January     Bill          returning
```

So the query I'm looking for should get a count for each unique personid that has "returning" unless a "new" exists for that personid as well - in this instance returning a `count` of 1 for

`January Bill returning`

because john is new for the month.

The query I've tried is

`SELECT COUNT(distinct personid) as count FROM visit_info WHERE visitstat = 'Returning'  GROUP BY MONTH(date) ORDER BY date`

Unfortunately this counts "Returning" even if a "New" record exists for the person in that month.

Thanks in advance, hopefully I explained this clearly enough.

[SQL Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuTpP.png)

[Chart of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn52X.png)

Comment: It's not much of a data set, is it?

Comment: It's more than what I included but I figured it would be to big of a mess to include here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already wrote the "magic" word yourself, "exists". You can use exactly that, a `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT vi1.personid) count
       FROM visit_info vi1
       WHERE vi1.visitstat = 'Returning'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM visit_info vi2
                                    WHERE vi2.personid = vi1.personid
                                          AND year(vi2.date) = year(vi1.date)
                                          AND month(vi2.date) = month(vi1.date)
                                          AND vi2.visitstat = 'New')
       GROUP BY year(vi1.date),
                month(vi1.date)
       ORDER BY year(vi1.date),
                month(vi1.date);
```

I also recommend to include the year in the `GROUP BY` expression, as you otherwise might get unexpected results when the data spans more than one year. Also only use expressions included in the `GROUP BY` clause or passed to an aggregation function in the `ORDER BY` clause. MySQL, as opposed to virtually any other DBMS, might accept it otherwise, but may also produce weird results.

Comment: This one works, as well as the other. Is their anyway to make it so that the rows that it doesnt pull values from populate as null? Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I also faced one of the same scenarios I was dealing with a database. The possible way I did was to use group by with having clause and a subquery.